# Android skimageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: android

when i open php file from my browser : "http://192.168.1.30/save/load_image_from_db.php?id="+id;
the image is shown properly, but when i tryed to display it from an android apps it does not work and i get this error : skimageDecoder::Factory returned null.

the Bitmap object still null, even when i assign to it decodeStream of the stream i get from url.opencnnection().getStream() !

code :

```
 @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                String id = params[0];
                String add = "http://192.168.1.30/save/load_image_from_db.php?id="+id;
                URL url;
                Bitmap image = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL(add);
                    InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return image;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@Override
 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String id = params[0];
        String add = "http://192.168.1.30/save/load_image_from_db.php?id="+id;          
        Bitmap image = null;

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(add);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = (HttpResponse)client.execute(request);           
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufferedEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            InputStream inputStream = bufferedEntity.getContent();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i use api 23 , i don't get class HttpClient, i thing it is deprecated in api 23

Comment: You can add :  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'   in your application's gradle file to use HttpClient

Comment: Why suggest reverting back to a [deprecated and less efficient implementation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)? There must be a solution using  the current `HttpUrlConnection` (or possibly another open source library such as `OkHttp`).